# fetchmail получает почту только для одного пользователя

Tags: linux, email

Настроил fetchmail, вот что у меня в ~/.fetchmailrc

```
defaults mda "procmail -d %T"
ssl
set logfile=/home/firefedot/log/fetchmail.log
poll pop.yandex.ru
proto POP3
user 'ya.user1'
password 'passwd1'

poll pop.yandex.ru
proto POP3 port 995
user 'ya.user1'
password 'passwd1'
```

Вот так выглядит ~/.procmailrc

```
# .procmailrc - конфиг для procmail
    # Переменные
    #
    MAILDIR=/home/firefedot/Mail                    # каталог с почтой
    LOGFILE=/home/firefedot/Mail/procmail.log       # лог для записи всех операций
    DEFAULT=/home/firefedot/Mail/mbox               # файл для не отсортированных сообщений
    #
    # Правила сортировки почты
    #
    # Пример: сортировка почты, приходящей на e-mail user_name@host.ru
    :0
    * ^To.*ya.user1@yandex.ru                        # условие (To: user_name@host.ru)
    host_mail                                       # файл host_mail в каталоге MAILDIR

    #
    # Пример: автоматическая отсылка PGP-ключа
    0:
    * ^Subject.*PGP                                 # условие (Subject: PGP)
    | (formail -r ; cat /home/ашкуаувще/key.asc)    # вывести PGP-ключ
    | sendmail -t                                   # отправить его
```

Если введен в конфиге ya.user1 - это одна учетная запись, то в принципе все работает, и файл ~/Mail/mbox - заполняется письмами.

А если поменять учетку на ya.user2 или любую другую, в которой заведомо есть письма, то в логе пишется, что подключение прошло успешно, новых писем нет.

запускаю так: fetchmail -vk

В логе при пользователе ya.user2:

```
fetchmail: 6.3.26 запрашивает pop.yandex.ru (протокол POP3) на Чт 04 фев 2016 17:47:11: опрос начат
fetchmail: Попытка подключения к 213.180.193.37/995...соединение установлено.
fetchmail: Server certificate:
fetchmail: Запрашивающая организация: Unizeto Technologies S.A.
fetchmail: Общепринятое имя: Certum Level IV CA
fetchmail: Subject CommonName: pop.yandex.ru
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop3.yandex.kz
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.yandex.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop3.yandex.ua
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.yandex.by
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop3.yandex.by
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.ya.ru
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.yandex.kz
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop3.yandex.com.tr
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop3.yandex.ru
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop3.yandex.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.yandex.ua
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop3.ya.ru
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.yandex.com.tr
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.yandex.ru
fetchmail: Отпечаток ключа pop.yandex.ru:  B1:91:A1:78:14:7B:0C:DB:1F:8D:B7:F3:B2:F2:0D:11
fetchmail: POP3< +OK POP Ya! na@26 MoLmjWCfvOsg
fetchmail: POP3> CAPA
fetchmail: POP3< +OK Capability list follows
fetchmail: POP3< STLS
fetchmail: POP3< TOP
fetchmail: POP3< USER
fetchmail: POP3< LOGIN-DELAY 60
fetchmail: POP3< PIPELINING
fetchmail: POP3< EXPIRE NEVER
fetchmail: POP3< UIDL
fetchmail: POP3< RESP-CODE
fetchmail: POP3< AUTH-RESP-CODE
fetchmail: POP3< IMPLEMENTATION Yandex
fetchmail: POP3< .
fetchmail: POP3> USER ya.user2
fetchmail: POP3< +OK password, please.
fetchmail: POP3> PASS *
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 0 0
fetchmail: POP3> STAT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 0 0
fetchmail: Для ya.user2 на pop.yandex.ru почты нет
fetchmail: POP3> QUIT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK shutting down.
fetchmail: 6.3.26 запрашивает pop.yandex.ru (протокол POP3) на Чт 04 фев 2016 17:47:11: опрос завершен
fetchmail: нормальное завершение, статус 1
```

По какой причине при одном логине/пароле он вроде как работает, а при другом(-их) не работает, при этом соедиенние создает, но писем не видит?

Вот тот-же кусок лога для ya.user1

```
fetchmail: считывается сообщение ya.user1@pop.yandex.ru:257 из 764 (32481 октетов) не очищено 
fetchmail: POP3> LIST 258 
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 258 37434463 
fetchmail: POP3> RETR 258 
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 37434463 octets.
```

Система archlinux*64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

запрос [статистики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP3#STAT) почтового хранилища:

```
fetchmail: POP3> STAT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 0 0
```

сервер ответил: ноль писем, ноль байт.

---

> По какой причине при одном логине/пароле он вроде как работает, а при другом(-их) не работает, при этом соедиенние создает, но писем не видит?

возможно потому, что взаимодействие по протоколу *pop3* [не разрешено](https://yandex.ru/support/mail/mail-clients.xml) пользователем (насколько я знаю, по умолчанию — запрещено).

---

если взаимодействие по протоколу *pop3* разрешено в *web-интерфейсе*, то имеет смысл обратиться в техподдержку сервиса, приведя лог взаимодействия с сервером и упомянув, что взаимодействие разрешено.